# How to use in browser a JS file generated from IcedCoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, client-side, iced-coffeescript

When I use vanilla CoffeeScript, I compile a *.coffee files and send resulted *.js to client.
To get rid of dependence on the module async.js in client side, I found the IcedCoffeeScript language extension. But when I compiled my code (wich has `await` and `defer` keywords) into *.js, in result I found non-client-side code:

```
iced = require('iced-coffee-script').iced;
```

So I can't use it in client side. Could to solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the --runtime flag on iced compiler to "inline".
http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script/

Answer (score 0):

I use the following gist successfully in production with version 1.6.3-g

https://gist.github.com/littleloops/7546859